# Weird shadows when using solidify modifier on hollow cylinders

Tags: unity, shadows

I'm seeing weird shadows when using the solidify modifier on hollow cylinders. I've verified all normals are correct. I can't seem to find any way to fix this. The shadow problems carry over to Unity when imported. What can I do to fix this?

[image: blender shadows]
[image: unity shadows]

Comment: Add an *Edge Split* modifier to your objects or turn on *Auto Smooth* in the *Object Data* tab

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos Will the Auto Smooth export to Unity?

Comment: @cmomoney Yes AFAIK.

Comment: Not sure, never used Unity but if it doesn't, *Edge Split* most likely will.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it could be a smoothing problem. Try using a *Edge Split* modifier after the *Solidify* modifier.